# Get data from PLC (micrologix 1100) to python

Tags: python, plugins, plc

I"m looking for get data of a PLC with python to make a lot of work with it.I only need get the "0" and "1" value. I found this python library pycomm ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycomm/1.0.7 ) where is this snippet too:

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.slc import Driver as SlcDriver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = SlcDriver(True, 'delete_slc.log')
    if c.open('172.16.2.160'):

        print c.read_tag('S:1/5')
        print c.read_tag('S:60', 2)

        print c.write_tag('N7:0', [-30, 32767, -32767])
        print c.write_tag('N7:0', 21)
        print c.read_tag('N7:0', 10)

        print c.write_tag('F8:0', [3.1, 4.95, -32.89])
        print c.write_tag('F8:0', 21)
        print c.read_tag('F8:0', 3)

        print c.write_tag('B3:100', [23, -1, 4, 9])
        print c.write_tag('B3:100', 21)
        print c.read_tag('B3:100', 4)

        print c.write_tag('T4:3.PRE', 431)
        print c.read_tag('T4:3.PRE')
        print c.write_tag('C5:0.PRE', 501)
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.PRE')
        print c.write_tag('T4:3.ACC', 432)
        print c.read_tag('T4:3.ACC')
        print c.write_tag('C5:0.ACC', 502)
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.ACC')

        c.write_tag('T4:2.EN', 0)
        c.write_tag('T4:2.TT', 0)
        c.write_tag('T4:2.DN', 0)
        print c.read_tag('T4:2.EN', 1)
        print c.read_tag('T4:2.TT', 1)
        print c.read_tag('T4:2.DN',)

        c.write_tag('C5:0.CU', 1)
        c.write_tag('C5:0.CD', 0)
        c.write_tag('C5:0.DN', 1)
        c.write_tag('C5:0.OV', 0)
        c.write_tag('C5:0.UN', 1)
        c.write_tag('C5:0.UA', 0)
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.CU')
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.CD')
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.DN')
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.OV')
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.UN')
        print c.read_tag('C5:0.UA')

        c.write_tag('B3:100', 1)
        print c.read_tag('B3:100')

        c.write_tag('B3/3955', 1)
        print c.read_tag('B3/3955')

        c.write_tag('N7:0/2', 1)
        print c.read_tag('N7:0/2')

        print c.write_tag('O:0.0/4', 1)
        print c.read_tag('O:0.0/4')

    c.close()
```

Excuse me for my unknown, but the only thing what i need know if is enought "Change" the (172.16.2.160) ip to link to the PLC, right?

"And select the correct tags"

Thank you for the future help and sorry for this "rare question" i can"t test the code with a PLC right now. (maybe in few weeks) So i cannot try succesfully this part of the code. And i need start to work in the other part.(Only for be sure what i can get the data with python. If you know another library in python please tell me that option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the IP address is enough.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer